# Bootstrap 5 - SassError: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color

Tags: vue.js, npm, sass, bootstrap-5

yesterday I updated my Vue project to the latest Bootstrap version (5.2) and now I have a SASS Error while starting.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                              10:45:42

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/config/modern/app.scss

Syntax Error: SassError: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color
        on line 185 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `red`
        from line 185 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `luminance`
        from line 174 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `contrast-ratio`
        from line 159 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `color-contrast`
        from line 7 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_accordion.scss
        from line 29 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
        from line 15 of src/assets/scss/config/modern/bootstrap.scss
        from line 19 of src/assets/scss/config/modern/app.scss
>>     "r": red($color),
```

It's about this code snippet:

```
// File: _functions.scss
// Return WCAG2.1 relative luminance
// See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#dfn-relative-luminance
// See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#dfn-contrast-ratio
@function luminance($color) {
  $rgb: (
    "r": red($color),
    "g": green($color),
    "b": blue($color)
  );

  @each $name, $value in $rgb {
    $value: if(divide($value, 255) < .03928, divide(divide($value, 255), 12.92), nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    $rgb: map-merge($rgb, ($name: $value));
  }

  @return (map-get($rgb, "r") * .2126) + (map-get($rgb, "g") * .7152) + (map-get($rgb, "b") * .0722);
}
```

And that's the trigger:

```
// File: _accordion.scss
// scss-docs-start accordion-css-vars
  --#{$prefix}accordion-color: #{color-contrast($accordion-bg)};
```

I know, the error says, the function gets a wrong parameter, which is not of type color, but I never user it my self.

[image]

How can I fix this error and why does it occur?

Comment: What was the previous version of Bootstrap before upgrading?

Comment: Bootstrap 5.1.3